# Doing queries on firebase

Tags: android, request, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase in my android app, but i'm facing problems. For example. I have this entrie

```
persons
    -kskhdhksdhh
        name:"Vladimir"
        age:"25"
        sexe:"M"
        country:"Russia"
    -jhgsdhghsgs
        name:"Victoria"
        age:"20"
        sexe:"F"
        country:"England"
    -zejhbshevzh
        name:"John"
        age:"44"
        sexe:"M"
        country:"England"
```

I want to select males living in England. How do I rearrange my data to get there knowing we can not do two orderby

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: Firebase queries can only order on one property (or priority or key). But in cases such as this, you can combine the values into a single property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase/26701282#26701282

Answer (score 2):

First - take a look at this answer , for similar question:
[Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase#tab-top)

Anyway, you can add country level to your data structure, so your data can look something like:

```
persons
    -Russia
       -kskhdhksdhh
           name:"Vladimir"
           age:"25"
           sexe:"M"
     -England
       -jhgsdhghsgs
           name:"Victoria"
           age:"20"
           sexe:"F"
       -zejhbshevzh
           name:"John"
           age:"44"
           sexe:"M"
```

Then you can easily query for males living in England.

Another option that described in the link on the top , is to add a key that combine both country & gender, and then query this property.